# How to get Json object to AjaxError function ??? (JsonResult not get in ajaxError Function in Live server)

Tags: jquery, .net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some issues with JSON and AJAX. I have an authentication class which has the following Logic:

This `HandleUnauthorizedRequest()` is called every time when a user makes a request and this method checks whether the user is logged in or not. If not, then it redirects to the login page.

```
public class AuthorizeUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (ApplicationSession.CurrentUserId == 0)
        {
            string filepath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\Log\\");
            string url = string.Format("{0}?reason=nav", System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
            Utility.LogFileWrite("Step 1: LoginUrl" + System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, filepath);
            Utility.LogFileWrite("Step 1.1: url" + url, filepath);
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                var redirectResult = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
                if (filterContext.Result is RedirectResult)
                {
                    // It was a RedirectResult => we need to calculate the url
                    var result = filterContext.Result as RedirectResult;
                    url = UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(result.Url, filterContext.HttpContext);
                }
                else if (filterContext.Result is RedirectToRouteResult)
                {
                    // It was a RedirectToRouteResult => we need to calculate
                    // the target url
                    var result = filterContext.Result as RedirectToRouteResult;
                    url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(result.RouteName, null, null, result.RouteValues, RouteTable.Routes,
                        filterContext.RequestContext, false);
                }
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
                {
                    Data = new {Redirect = url},
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,

                };
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(filterContext.Result);
                Utility.LogFileWrite("Step 2: Result:" + json, filepath);
            }
            else
            {
                //non-ajax request
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                    new RouteValueDictionary(
                        new
                        {
                            controller = "Account",
                            action = "Login"
                        })
                    );
                //base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

In the View I have added the following script:

```
 jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    //show ajax indicator
    $('#map_loading').show();
}).ajaxStop(function () {
    //hide ajax indicator
    $('#map_loading').hide();
}).ajaxSuccess(function (event, request, settings) {

}).ajaxError(function (event, request, settings) {
    debugger;
    if (request.status == 403) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(request.responseText);           
        if (request.responseJSON.Redirect) {
            window.location.replace(request.responseJSON.Redirect);
        }
    }
});
```

So, my problem is that when a user not logged in, its enters in to the ajaxError function but, there is "request" which does not return a JSONResult.

This functionality works fine on a local server, but when live I get an error of:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Redirect' of undefined

On the local server I get a JSON Object [Local AjaxError Method Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsKa2.png)

but when Live I do not get the JSON Object. Instead of responseText I get by default the 403 Html Page as shown below [Live AjaxError Method Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiVGh.png)

Can anyone please give me a solution as to how to get a Json result in the ajax function? And why does it work in local but not live.